# printf "$V" fails when it's: '^+%&/%+^

Tags: printf

To avoid **\n**:
using "**printf**" rather than "**echo**"

Set **String**

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' V <<'EOF'
'^+%&/%+^
EOF
```

Test w/ **echo** ( works fine )

```
echo "$V"
'^+%&/%+^
```

Test w/ **printf** ( fails )

```
printf "$V"
bash: printf: `&': invalid format character
```

Comment: @terdon In case you didn't follow this from the beginning, the OP was deleting his questions after receiving answers.  But, if you need a bad guy to point to and you picked me, sure, I'm here, ready and willing. _shrug_

Comment: @SatoKatsura I know, I have been following closely. And I wasn't saying you did anything wrong, sorry if it came across that way. The only "bad guy" here is the user who deletes useful questions, certainly not you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `printf` will be interpreted as a formatting string, and `%&` is an invalid format specifier.

Try this instead:

```
printf '%s' "$V"
```

The formatting that `printf` does should be explained in the `printf(1)` manual, or in the manual of your shell.  The `%s` format simply means "expect a string". The `printf` utility does not add a newline by default.